# Understand if a function is linear or nonlinear with neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, neural-network, nonlinear-functions

I have data from simulation that are a combination of a restrict range of inputs, this could be an example:

```
Y=(X1*X2)^2+X3
X1=[1,2]
X2=[2,5]
X3=[10,20]
```

The Y function is a non linear function, but, having a results of all the combination (with these X), I am able to train a Regression Neural Network with no hidden layer and without use any activation functions like a linear function.

My problem is that I don't know if my function is linear or nonLinear but I can dimostrate with the example above that with this restricted range of input in the neural network the function results linear. Is it normal and correct? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking here is:

> What makes a function linear?

I am not a mathematician, but I believe that: if your function can be plotted in a straight line it is indeed linear (see: [link](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/linear.html)). Otherwise you will need some non-linear function to plot it.

I am a bit confused by the function `X` that you are asking about. But If all you are doing is combining the outputs of a nonlinear function `Y`, then yes your function is linear and operating on the result of a non-linear function. This is done frequently in neural networks and in dimensionality reduction cases where inputs are transformed into a space where linear separation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Y is a regression function of your Input X where in here, X is a vector of  x1, x2 and x3. It is a linear function only if Y=AX+b where A is some matrix and b is a vector. In you case, it is not a linear function. Since the square term in your function. More specifically in your case, only Y=a*x1+b*x2+c*x3+d (Y is scalar) is a linear regression where a, b, c, d are parameters you may want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the input means that you are giving two values for each independent variable of the function. Since you only have two inputs for the triple `(X1, X2, X3)`, you are guaranteed to have a linear relationship. You will need to provide additional inputs in order to determine non-linearity.